# How to plot a set of densities in 3D using R?

Tags: r, 3d, plot

I need to plot, in 3D, a set of densities associated to a time series. More precisely, I would like to be able in R to build an image close to this example:

[image: a 3D perspective plot of density traces: from https://web.archive.org/web/20140801002925/https://sites.google.com/site/agenbiteofinwit/home/plotDensity3D.png]

This image is taken from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PdX3.png). The transparency plays an important role as let us see the trajectory of the "measures" in the x-y plane.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PdX3.png): Juban and Kariniotakis, "Uncertainty Estimation of Wind Power Forecasts", presentation at EWEC 2008 - 01 April - Brussels, Belgium. (I can't post the link, google will help interested readers).

Comment: This is pretty, but is it really useful? Even with the transparency, it is very hard to track and compare different trajectories.

Comment: Yes it is useful. The trick is not to track or compare trajectories, but to have a visual estimation of the uncertainty of a forecaster. 


The usefulness concept is very context dependent, and in my context such a pretty graph can be a very useful graph.

Comment: I am skeptical that this is the best plot for any task - the perceptual decoding of a rotated 3d plot like this is extremely difficult, not to mention the problems with foreground objects obscuring background objects.

Comment: Would you suggest any alternative to display this information?

Comment: The third dimension (z-axis in this case) could be color. In your plot, it seems that color and height are conveying the same variable.

Comment: I would think facetted line plots would be the way to go.

Comment: battle of gods: Hadley Wickham vs Rob Hyndman :D

Answer (score 5):

In 1996 I wrote a paper (published in JCGS) with a figure very similar to that but without the transparency. See http://robjhyndman.com/papers/estimating-and-visualizing-conditional-densities/ for the details. The plotting function is implemented in the R package [hdrcde](http://robjhyndman.com/software/hdrcde/) available on CRAN. The package contains some examples in the help files. You should be able to adapt my code to add the transparency.

Comment: Thanks!

I'm looking into your code, but I think I need to master the persp function first... doesn't look as an easy task!

Answer (score 1):

This is how far I got thanks to Rob's hint. I used persp() to create an empty plot and added polygons and lines to it:

[image]

However, it is not as pretty as the original one... :(

Comment: this post does similar plots in python though it's lacking the 3D view: http://sbebo.github.io/blog/blog/2017/08/01/joypy/