# How to create 3D stacked distributions in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I would like te create a 3D graph of normal distributions in R. I found an image of what I'm looking for in an [Origin blog](http://blog.originlab.com/graphing/how-to-create-3d-stacked-histograms-with-their-fitted-curves). I've copy-pasted the image. 
Thanks in advance!
[image: Link to image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297552/how-to-plot-a-set-of-densities-in-3d-using-r. Although there's no nice answer over there.

Comment: [Here](https://statisfaction.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/3d-density-plot-in-r-with-plotly/) is an example using the `plotly` package.